# Spring transactions and postgres (VACUUM, run outside transaction)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp

When running the postgres query `VACUUM ANALYZE my_table;` I always get the same error in spring boot with HikariCP.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block
```

From my understanding it should work with `@Propagation.NEVER`, but I can't get it to work.

```java
/**
* Execute non-transactionally, throw an exception if a transaction exists.
* Analogous to EJB transaction attribute of the same name.
*/
NEVER(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_NEVER),
```

If I set hikari to `auto-commit: true` it works, but I don't want to do that.

How can I achieve running `VACUUM` without turning `auto-commit` on?

Comment: What's wrong with autocommit? Just start a transaction if you need one. That's how PostgreSQL operates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to this.

The best one is to never call `VACUUM` and instead tune `AUTOVACUUM` to run appropriately.

The second solution is to use `auto-commit` when using PostgreSQL, but make sure you use a transactional scope when needed. In the case of java and spring that would be using the annotation `@Transactional`.